# java spring security, if login user is disabled, how to know password is wrong or not

Tags: spring-security

```
**Login** in *spring security*, when user is disabled, i can't know the password is wrong or not.
please,tell me how.
[AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider][1]
```

in spring security:

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(){
 // (1) check disabled, if disabled, ***throw exception***
 preAuthenticationChecks.check(user);
 // (2)check password
 additionalAuthenticationChecks(user, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
```

### Heading

```
(1)`public void check(UserDetails user) {
        if (!user.isAccountNonLocked()) {
            logger.debug("User account is locked");

            throw new LockedException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.locked",
                    "User account is locked"), user);
        }

        if (!user.isEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("User account is disabled");

            throw new DisabledException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled",
                    "User is disabled"), user);
        }

        if (!user.isAccountNonExpired()) {
            logger.debug("User account is expired");

            throw new AccountExpiredException(messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.expired",
                    "User account has expired"), user);
        }
    }`
```

(2)`protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Object salt = null;

```
    if (this.saltSource != null) {
        salt = this.saltSource.getSalt(userDetails);
    }

    if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
        logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");

        throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"), userDetails);
    }

    String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userDetails.getPassword(), presentedPassword, salt)) {
        logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");

        throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"), userDetails);
    }
}`
```

}

}

Comment: if the user is disabled, why do you want to check the password?

Comment: @ArunPJohny If password is wrong, return login page; else redirect user activating page

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to add a redirect in the login page

```
AuthenticationException ex = ((AuthenticationException) request.getSession().getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION));
if(ex instanceof DisabledException){
    //Send redirect
}
```

Comment: If password is wrong, AuthenticationException is instance of DisabledException too.

Comment: no, it is the otherway around, `DisabledException` is a subclass of `AuthenticationException ` and wrong password will give another subclass called `BadCredentialException`

Comment: I mean that when user is disabled and input wrong password, only get DisabledException